# How to create a SwiftUI menu that has multi color label

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want the SFSymbol to have a blue color and text to be black. But the entire text changes color to blue when passed to label.

I saw [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ow8bRY2McE) example of a custom `MenuStyle` used to set custom background and foreground colors on the menu label. Can I use that to create a multi-colored menu item label?

```
Menu {
  Button("Title 1", action: {})
  Button("Title 2", action: {})
} label: {
  Text("Share") + Text(Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")).foregroundColor(.red)
}
```

Comment: I just had to make this change`Text("Share").foregroundColor(.black)`.

Comment: Hello, @Parth! I've provided a solution directly in the answer section. I hope it resolves your issue. If it doesn't, please let me know, and I'll be happy to explore alternative solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily customize the appearance of the button by setting different foreground styles for the text and the SF Symbol image. Here's the updated code:

```
Menu {
    Button("Title 1", action: {})
    Button("Title 2", action: {})
} label: {
    Text("Share")
        .foregroundStyle(.black)
    + Text(Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up"))
        .foregroundStyle(.blue)
}
```

It's worthy to mention that similarly you can apply various modifiers to different pieces of text and then combine them into a single label, as demonstrated here:

```
Text("Black Text")
   .foregroundStyle(.black)
   .font(.title)
+ Text(" Blue Text")
   .foregroundColor(.blue)
   .fontWeight(.bold)
```

[image: Multi-modifier label]

Note: `.foregroundColor` will be deprecated in a future version of iOS, so used `.foregroundStyle` instead.